# Returning JSON Data from inside loop

Tags: json, swift, function

I am trying to return the values that i get from the JSON response

```
    func getAsset(imageId: String) -> String{
    let url = "https://myimage.com"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    let singleAsset = json["fields"]["file"]["url"].string
                    print(singleAsset)
                }
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to return the value (singleAsset) but cant because i keep getting the error unresolved identifier. Ive been trying all night but cant return to value.

Answer (score 1):

You should use completion handlers:
See: https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/

```
func getAsset(imageId: String, completion: (String) -> Void) {
    let url = "https://myimage.com"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    let singleAsset = json["fields"]["file"]["url"].string
                    print(singleAsset)
                    completion(singleAsset)
                }
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
            completion(nil);
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
getAsset(imageId) {result in
    println("got back: \(result)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works but how do i take the value i got out the function? I want to use the output somewhere else in the code not just the function

Comment: So i want the value of results to be used elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Keep that in a property

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you send a request to any web API endpoint, the response is never instantaneous and may take some time. That is why you're actually passing a block of code to `Alamofire.request` that is run whenever a response is received.

You could also pass a block as a parameter to `getAsset` function and execute it whenever the response is received (as pointed out by @arturdev already in his answer)

Additionally, you could also have a singleton class and implement a delegate/protocol structure that notifies your view controllers whenever there is a response.